# Prevent Visual Studio 2013 build from upgrading certain Telerik dlls automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, telerik

How to prevent updating certain telerik dlls in Visual Studio 2013?

I am trying to prevent Telerik.Web.UI.dll from upgrading to a different version with a different version timestamp because I have some legacy code that is causing issues so sticking with the existing version is preferable.  The same issue existing for Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll with the same version numbers (see below).

Working version is 2011.3.1305.35 and the Non-Working version is 2015.3.1111.45

I don't know if I need to load the 2011 version on my computer and also have the 2015 version in the toolbox at the same time to make it an optional compile.

Is it also possible to prevent this from updating when I first load up the visual studio project?  Finally is it possible to keep the current version of Telerik control panel settings and without reverting to older version of the control panel just keep current settings?

Answer (score 0):

To fix for my case: Right Click the Project in solution explorer that contains the dlls.  Then Update the Property Pages by removing the "Auto Update" versions for both Telerik.Web.UI.dll and Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll by selecting them and then hitting the "Remove" button under the Reference section which should be the top most section in "Property Pages".

This would probably work for any dll that is automatically updating when opening visual studio or hitting the compile button.   By removing the "Auto Update" version of type BIN for these two reference dlls, it essentially leaves theme alone when building the project.

I'll have to test these with regard to the Telerik Control Panel to see how and when it updates the references section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the properties that you refer to in my copy of VS2013 (perhaps we use different types of projects) but I had posed this question to the folks at Telerik before.

What I was trying to do was to have a network folder store very tightly controlled copies of the Telerik libraries as my application was being tested against those versions and I didn't want anything changing.

However I also wanted to keep up to date for other projects and to evaluate bug fixes. When I received updates to those libraries, I would install the updates using the Telerik installer (and leave them there, which is the problem), and then VS2013 would find the files in the GAC and update my project's references to those versions when I re-opened a project.

The response from the Telerik support staff indicated that a likely solution would be to use the network drive as I was doing, and just remove all versions from my PC after downloading and safely storing the updates away somewhere. This seems to be similar to other solutions I've seen on SO as well.